# Western Digital Blue WDC WD60EZAZ works unstable

Tags: command-line, 22.04, hard-drive, lts

I have a problem with the operation of the WDC WD60EZAZ-00SF3B0 disk in Ubuntu 22.04.

```
[41465.303694] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[41465.303697] ata3: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake DevExch }
[41465.303702] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[41465.303705] ata3.00: cmd 60/18:70:90:ed:04/00:00:62:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 12288 in
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[41465.303713] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[41465.303716] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[41465.303718] ata3.00: cmd 61/00:a0:00:a6:72/0a:00:02:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[41465.303726] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[41465.303729] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[41465.303730] ata3.00: cmd 61/00:a8:00:b0:72/0a:00:02:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[41465.303737] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[41465.303740] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[41465.303742] ata3.00: cmd 61/00:b0:00:ba:72/0a:00:02:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[41465.303749] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[41465.303751] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[41465.303753] ata3.00: cmd 61/00:b8:00:c4:72/04:00:02:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 524288 out
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[41465.303760] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[41465.303764] ata3: hard resetting link
[41472.063593] ata3: found unknown device (class 0)
[41474.299571] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[41474.312959] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[41474.312983] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[41474.312987] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[41474.312991] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[41474.312994] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 62 04 ed 90 00 00 00 18 00 00
[41474.312996] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1644490128 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 2
[41474.313015] ata3: EH complete
```

Is it necessary to force the kernel to work with delay for this disk?

```
libata.force=3.00:noncq,1.5g,nolpm,dbdelay
```

Comment: It could be a firmware issue or it could be a cable issue (connection between drive and controller).  See https://serverfault.com/questions/952148/failed-command-write-fpdma-queued-cause-of-server-running-slow  I think I would try the cable first by reseating it on the drive and making sure it is tight in the drive and to the motherboard.  If still the same thing, replace the SATA cable.  Very last would be to update the firmware for the drive (if one is available) but the only way I can see from Western Digital is either through Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: Just a note here, from thinking about it I had a file server that has a 20TB array in it and it was giving the same errors.  It did turn out to be a loose connection.  I ended up replacing all the SATA cables in that system with locking ones and I have never had an issue with them since.

Comment: I tested the hdd in Windows and did not notice any strange behavior during disk operation, but in Ubuntu the disk begins to report problems in operation. Currently the disk works quite well with 'lpm' disabled and with 'dbdelay' extra 200ms delay

Comment: Next time please add any other things you have tried like Windows tests into your question so that we are not guessing the issues you are having.  Have you checked for firmware updates from the WD Dashboard for your drive in Windows?

Comment: This behavior is repeated with the second disk that was replaced under warranty. There is no option to update the BIOS in the WD Dashboard, and WD customer service suggests formatting the disk or looking for bad sectors.

Comment: it seems that WD only supports Windows OS and MacOS :)

Comment: Is there ANY that supports Linux? I doubt it.

Comment: I have 3 WD Blue drives in this system here and they are not giving any errors in Ubuntu.  There could honestly be a problem with the firmware version of that drive and Ubuntu.  Of course, I am not using any 6TB drives like you are though.  My largest Blue is only 2TB.

Answer (score 1):

Noted: your log time points jumps 7 seconds at errors.

Tip:

`$ sudo apt install smartmontools`

Then run `lsblk -ape7 -o +FSUSE%,LABEL` to see disk device names (among partitions).

and use
`$ sudo smartclt -a /dev/sda`
*(an example: assuming a /dev/sda disk listed among lsblk output)*

Ponder on the results; is there errors listed?
*If not, reason to believe your cabling is to be suspected.*

smartctl value INTERPRETATION:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6983?page=0%2C1

Comment: [WD NAS Drives](https://youtu.be/cLGi8sPLkLY?si=hTJK7fY2eKaTgOIe)

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you are seeing indicate that your WDC WD60EZAZ-00SF3B0 disk is experiencing ATA bus errors. This means that the communication between the disk and the SATA controller is being disrupted. This can be caused by a variety of factors, including:

- A faulty disk cable
- A faulty SATA controller
- A faulty disk drive
- A driver issue
- A BIOS or UEFI issue

To troubleshoot the problem, you can try the following:

1. Check the disk cable and make sure that it is properly connected to both the disk drive and the SATA controller.
2. Try using a different SATA cable.
3. Try connecting the disk drive to a different SATA port on the motherboard.
4. Update the SATA controller driver.
5. Update the BIOS or UEFI firmware.

If you have tried all of the above and you are still seeing ATA bus errors, then it is likely that the disk drive itself is faulty. In this case, you will need to replace the disk drive.

Here are some additional troubleshooting tips:

- Run a SMART test on the disk drive to check for any physical errors.
- Try booting from a live Linux USB drive and running a disk benchmark tool to see if the problem is reproducible.
- If you are using a RAID array, try disabling RAID and connecting the disk drive directly to the motherboard.

Comment: in my opinion, my disk may be susceptible to an LPM problem [bugzilla-57211](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57211)